# Minimal cost cyclic path in a graph - A variant of TSP

Tags: algorithm, graph

For example, we have a graph consisting of vertices (cities) and edges (roads) and each edge(road) has a particular cost, find the minimal cost to visit all cities **ATLEAST ONCE**. Cost is the sum of the edge costs of the edges traversed.
The part "ATLEAST ONCE" caught me. In a TSP we can visit a node only once according to Wiki. Consider the graph,
A-B 11
A-C 5
B-C 2
B-E 4
C-E 3
C-D 20
D-E 100
In a TSP, The cyclic path would be A-B-E-D-C-A cost- 140 (or) A-C-D-E-B-A cost- 140. Where as from my problem description we can visit each vertex ATLEAST ONCE so we can have a cyclic path A-C-D-C-E-B-A cost- 63 which is << a TSP. This is where I had a problem. Any specific algorithm here? I'm pretty sure TSP wont work well here.
Pointers or pseudo code will be very helpful.

Comment: The cost matrix can be changed so that it becomes tsp. Eg d to e should not be 100 but 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each pair of nodes, you can apply the [shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and calculate the shortest distance. This will be the new cost matrix for each pair.

Now it is reduced to [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Then you can apply TSP solving technique.

Comment: This is what I initially thought, but I'm not convinced that there isn't a more efficient way - the fact that paths include vertices changes the problem - e.g. the shortest path from the starting vertex A to some vertex B can cover all other vertices, thus simply going A -> B -> A would be the solution. Though the worst/average-case would likely require solving the TSP.

Comment: @Dukeling You're right, in that case, the minimum cost between A and B shall be so high that A->B directly wouldn't come into the solution. However, the TSP solver shall handle it IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are allowing a vertex to be visited multiple times, this effectively turns your incomplete graph into a complete graph (all vertices connected), which is what TSP requires. Solving your problem in the general case is exactly the same as solving the metric TSP. The good news is that this is a heavily researched topic. The bad news is that you aren't able to sidestep the TSP - since your problem is identical to a form of the TSP.

As pointed out by others, you complete the graph by computing the shortest cost between each pair of vertices and adding those edges where missing. You also need to replace any existing direct edge for which you've found a lower indirect path cost so that you have a [Metric TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Metric_TSP). You can store with the new synthetic edges their actual paths (through intermediate vertices) so you can recover those for your final answer, or you can recompute those paths as needed upon receiving the result of the TSP.

Now you can solve this as a TSP. However, solving TSP optimally is too expensive in the general case, so you'll likely want to use an approximate solution algorithm. A variety of these (e.g. Christofides algorithm, Lin–Kernighan heuristic) are available which make differing tradeoffs between guaranteed levels of optimality and performance of the algorithm.

If you actually don't care about completing the cycle, and just want a minimum path that visits all vertices, starting and ending at any vertex, this is a somewhat different problem. For this, read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33601043/5237297